# Cannot listen to https on port 5050 in NGINX

Tags: node.js, nginx, https, digital-ocean

I have a nodejs app that functions as a webserver listening to port 5050

I've created certificates and configured NGINX which works for normal https calls to the standard port (https://x.x/)

If I make a call to port 5050 with a normal http://x.x:5050 call it also works, but with an https://x.x:5050/conf call I get: This site can’t provide a secure connection

Below the NGINX config file:
(The names of the website are changed)

```
server {

        root /var/www/x.x/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name x.x www.x.x;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /conf {
               proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /wh {
               proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
               proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/x.x/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/x.x/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You configured nginx to serve as a reverse proxy, forwarding incoming requests from `https://example.com/whatever` to `http://localhost:5050/whatever`. You said you did that correctly and it works. Good. (Getting that working is a notorious pain in the xxx neck.)

You did not configure nginx to listen on port 5050. Nor should you; that's the port it uses to pass along requests to your nodejs program. You cannot forward requests from port 5050 to port 5050. If you try to have nodejs and nginx both listen to port 5050, one of them will get an EADRINUSE error when you start your servers.

Your nodejs program listens for http requests, not https requests, on port 5050. You can't easily make it listen for both http and https on the same port.  Your nodejs program, when behind nginx, should not contain any https server, only http. (You're making nginx do the hard crypto work to handle https, and letting nodejs handle your requests.)

Nor do you want your nodejs program to listen directly for http-only requests from outside your server. Because cybercreeps.

If you can block access to port 5050 from anywhere except localhost, you can declare victory on your task of configuring your server. You [can do this](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_options_callback) by using

````js
server.listen({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5050, ...
});```
````

in your nodejs program. Or you can configure your server's firewall to block incoming requests on any ports except https (and ssh, so you can manage it). Digital Ocean has a [useful tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-20-04) on this point.

Comment: Apparently the forwarding from "https ://x.x:5050/conf" to http :// is not working. A call to http ://x.x:5050/conf however is working. Moreover if I understood reverse proxy correctly then I there is no need for the nodejs server to listen to https

Comment: Correct. It's incorrect to forward requests from `https://example.com:5050` to `http://localhost:5050`.